What is the difference between @classmethod, @staticmethod, and instance methods in Python?
What is the difference between @classmethod, @staticmethod, and instance methods in Python?
I’ve been experimenting with each type of method in a Python class to understand the differences and when to use each one. Here’s what I tried:
Instance Method: I created a regular instance method and noticed that it requires an instance to call it. It seems to use self to access instance-specific data.
Class Method: I added a method with the @classmethod decorator and noticed it uses class instead of self. I’m able to call it directly from the class without creating an instance, but I’m not sure why or when I should use it instead of a regular method.

You can answer me in points or in brief explanations

"I'm trying to understand the practical scenarios where each type of method is preferred. I see that instance methods use self and work with instance-specific data, while @classmethod uses cls and can be called directly from the class.

Instance Methods
Definition: Regular methods in a class. They take self as their first parameter, which refers to the instance of the class.
Access: Can access and modify the instance's attributes and other instance methods.
Usage: Used when you need to operate on specific data tied to an instance of the class.
class MyClass:
    def instance_method(self):
        print(f"Called instance_method of {self}")

obj = MyClass()
obj.instance_method()  # Works: requires an instance
MyClass.instance_method()  # Error: no instance provided

Class Methods
Definition: Defined with the @classmethod decorator. They take cls as their first parameter, which refers to the class itself.
Access: Can access class-level data and methods but cannot directly access instance data.
Usage: Use class methods when you need to work with or modify the class itself, such as alternative constructors or class-wide operations.
class MyClass:
    class_variable = "shared data"

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
        print(f"Called class_method of {cls}")
        print(f"Class variable is {cls.class_variable}")

MyClass.class_method()  # Works: no instance needed

Example of an alternative constructor:
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, value_str):
        value = int(value_str)
        return cls(value)

obj = MyClass.from_string("42")  # Creates an instance with a class method

Static Methods
Definition: Defined with the @staticmethod decorator. They do not take self or cls as their first parameter.
Access: Cannot modify class or instance state. They behave like regular functions but live within the class's namespace.
Usage: Use static methods for utility functions that don't depend on the class or instance but are conceptually related.
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def static_method(arg):
        print(f"Called static_method with {arg}")

MyClass.static_method("hello")  # Works: no instance needed

